# find pairs of rows that have same column value

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server, I have a database table that models a collection of devices. Each device controls one or more regions, and each region can be either offline or online.

I cannot have a situation where the same region is online on more than one device.

table "FEP" schema is:

```
region_address [int]
region         [int]
online         [bit]
```

sample data:

```
region_address  region   online      
3001100         100      0
3002100         100      1
3002200         200      0
3002241         241      0
3001123         123      0
3003123         123      1
3928999         999      1
3921999         999      1
```

I need this query to list region 999 as being online on two (or more) listed devices.

I use a simple `select * from fep order by region` to visually see if any two successive rows have online = 1, but this doesn't identify ONLY conflicting regions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this a bit simpler

```
SELECT region
FROM FEP
WHERE online = 1
GROUP BY region
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

The issue with doing `Having count(distinct online)=1` is let's say there are 3 devices, 2 are online and 1 is not. So count(distinct online) would equal 2 but there are still multiple devices online and you would not catch that. The above would account for that, and it would also account for devices, even if there were NULL values (provided that there were at least 2 devices online as was the criteria)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti see this

Comment: @user3235770 see this edge case, if you have it, you'll need to account for it

Comment: @Eli  I'd be happy to cede the Accept, but I think we have different reads on the question.  My understanding is all alike not just a pair.   I've been wrong before :)

Comment: typical case is that there are two devices that have any particular region, but any number of devices are allowed with any number of regions each. The rule is that only one instance of any region may be online, so this edge case does need to be accounted for. Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti My attention wasn't to cede the credit for an accepted answer, rather, it was to bring attention to an edge case. My apologies if it came across otherwise.

Comment: @Eli No worries, I simply had a different understanding of the question which evolved through OP's comments.   No feelings where hurt  :)